# how to use hamcrest to compare text ignoring tabs?

Tags: java, string, unit-testing, testing, hamcrest

I have a test, I want to assert its result:

```
    assertThat(cofmanString, new IsEqualIgnoringCase(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/Users/myFile.txt"))));
```

in Intellij I see the strings are identical including tabs and newlines

actual:

[image]

expected:
[image]

but the test fails like this:

[image]

which hamcrest matcher can i use to compare the strings and succeed?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
assertThat(cofmanString, equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace(FileUtils.readFileToString(
new File("/Users/myFile.txt")).toLowerCase()));
```

You can see more for IsEqualIgnoringWhiteSpace [here](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/text/IsEqualIgnoringWhiteSpace.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "ignore tabs" option, but you can just remove all tabs before comparing by applying `.replace("\t", "")` to each term:

```
assertThat(cofmanString.replace("\t", ""), new IsEqualIgnoringCase(
  FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/Users/myFile.txt"))).replace("\t", ""));
```